# Not able to get incoming request's ip address in Node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get the incoming request's `ip` address in my one of `api` in `Node.js express`

I am getting `ip` like this

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
```

But it gives me `ip` address like this `::1`

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: ::1 is ipv6 for the localhost. Are you running this on your local host?

Comment: yes i am running `my node` server on localhost.

Comment: If the requests are also coming from localhost then it is correctly reflecting the incoming IP address.